# Creating a file via python on OpenShift application

Tags: python-2.7, file, flask, openshift

```
    with io.open("filepath/filename",mode="w",encoding="utf8") as file:        
        file.write(jsondata)
```

But it seems something wrong. 
my flaskapp return 500 and no error logs

But when i remove it everything can run as normal.

what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OpenShift 2, it is likely your web application is running under Apache/mod_wsgi. You shouldn't in that case be using relative path names as the current working directory of the application is effectively undefined and likely not writable. Instead construct an absolute path name. Depending on what file is for, you may be best to write files into the data directory provided to you and specified by the `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` environment variable, if it potentially needs to persist. Or `OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR` if a temporary file. Details of important variables for directories can be found in:

- https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html#directory-variables

As to why you aren't seeing any error, this is likely because Flask is swallowing the error up when generating the 500 response. You would need to configure Flask to log details of the error.

Comment: Thanks~       
you help me a lot ^ ^

Comment: [openshft flask example](https://github.com/openshift/flask-example)
for me to remember @@